# A basic intuitive question on basis

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, intuition

From Zorn's lemma, basis can be thought of as a maximal independent set as well as minimum cover (covering all the vectors). Is this observation correct ? Can this observation be related to the usual notion of graph theory where an independent set is just complement of vertex cover.

Comment: Well, there is *some* reason for the same naming occuring in both areas.

Comment: It may be that by "cover" you mean what is more usually known as "span" or "generating set", and then yes: a basis of a linear vector space over a field is a maximal linearly independent set = minimal generating set(=minimal spanning set).

Comment: Independent sets in graphs are also known as stable sets and as cocliques. It might be best not to read too much into the name.